# How to know if my nvidia gpu is working or not?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I've installed nvidia 375 drivers on my Ubuntu 16.04. How do I know if the drivers are working and the GPU is functioning? I typed `nvidia-smi`, and it says that my GPU is turned off. Is this normal or do I need anything else?

[image]

Comment: Use `prime-select nvidia` in the terminal and then reboot to activate your nvidia card. To return to integrated GPU use `prime-select intel`

Comment: Install `inxi` & then  run `inxi -G`   See what your `OpenGL: renderer:` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Run:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

If you got some output you're using Nvidia gpu but if there's no output then either you're using Intel's gpu or you're using nouveau drivers so try and run:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

If there's no output then you're definitely using Intel's gpu.

To switch between graphics card, open NVIDIA X Server Settings and clicl on PRIME Profiles on the left panel. Or as noted by @WinEunuuchs2Unix you can run `prime-select nvidia` for Nvidia or `prime-select intel` for choosing intel.

Another way is to check driver details inside graphic intensive programs or games which could give you a hint if you're using the right graphics card, (It depends on the program or game to have this feature in the menu). I suggest installing a game like OpenArena which has this freature if you just want to be absolutely sure you're using Nvidia.